# GTK3: how to subscribe to touchpad events?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk3, gtk4

I have tried to subscribe to touch events as:

```
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(hw), "touch-event", G_CALLBACK (gw_touch_event), pview);
```

but my `gw_touch_event` callback function is never called. Is it only for touch screens?

Question: how to receive touchpad events in GTK3 and in GTK4 ?

More details:

On "two-finger-scroll" gesture GdkEventScroll handler **correctly reports GDK_SOURCE_TOUCHPAD**:

```
GdkDevice *device = gdk_event_get_source_device(event);
if(!device) return;

GdkInputSource is = gdk_device_get_source (device);
bool is_touchpad = is == GDK_SOURCE_TOUCHPAD;
```

But Gtk Inspector application shows zero count of "touch-event" handler invocations.

Also my generic "event" signal handler also shows nothing here:

```
gboolean gw_event (GtkWidget* self, GdkEvent* event, gpointer user_data) {
  GdkEventType et = gdk_event_get_event_type (event);
  switch(et) {
    case GDK_TOUCH_BEGIN:
    case GDK_TOUCH_UPDATE:
    case GDK_TOUCH_END:
    case GDK_TOUCH_CANCEL:
    case GDK_TOUCHPAD_SWIPE:
    case GDK_TOUCHPAD_PINCH:
      g_message("TOUCH EVENT: %d",et);
      return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: What versions of libraries (GTK etc) are you using?  What do you get if you print ALL incoming events to `gw_event()`?  Have you added events to an event_mask, similar to `gtk_widget_add_events(window, GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK);`?

Comment: GTK version 3.24.33 

"Have you added events to an event_mask" - yes.

As of gw_event(), I am not getting GDK_TOUCH_BEGIN|UPDATE|END|CANCEL ... , will try to log all events later.